# Magento custom option price as default

Tags: magento

I have a product with Unit price and case price radio button set in the custom options
I want the Unit price to be selected as default in the `view.phtml` page how can I do this?
I have checked the function `getValuesHtml()` in `core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\select.php`
Where can I change it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I would suggest that you introduce some javascript that auto selects the first radio button.